# Keeping the Search Bar Permanent in a TableViewController

Tags: ios, scroll, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have a UISearchBar inside a UITableView (NOT UISearchBarDisplayController) and I am trying to achieve one thing:

1) Keep the Search Bar Permanent on top without scrolling when scrolling through the Table View.

With this, I have tried multiple things including:

[Locking a UISearchBar to the top of a UITableView like Game Center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870085/locking-a-uisearchbar-to-the-top-of-a-uitableview-like-game-center)

[Search bar is not getting fixed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13909986/search-bar-is-not-getting-fixed)

[Hide keyboard when scroll UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4399357/hide-keyboard-when-scroll-uitableview)

So setting the search bar as a subview and multiple other things, but I just cannot get the search bar to remain in place when scrolling through the Table View.

Any assistance on this would be very much appreciated!